# Is there a Windows app that can do FLV playlists?

Tags: windows, media-player, flv

Does anyone know of a Windows software that can do FLV playlists? In other words, you'd load a bunch of FLV files and have them play one after another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/) can do virtually anything to do with videos. If you're nice to it, it might even make you a cup of tea.

[image]

http://wiki.videolan.org/Flash_Video

[image]

http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Basic_Use/Playlist

Comment: Thanks, Jin. I have VLC Media Player but didn't know it could do this! Going to try it right now :)